# Identify unique values in a column and rename them in a new column

Tags: r, dataframe

I need some advice regarding data frame manipulation in R. I am doing cell clonality analysis and I am trying to group cells into expanded or unexpanded clones.

I have a data frame as below:

```
Cell    Ident   Count   Clonality
C1      A       5       Expanded
C2      B       3       Expanded
C3      A       5       Expanded
C4      C       2       Unexpanded
C5      A       5       Expanded
C6      B       3       Expanded
C7      C       2       Unexpanded
C8      A       5       Expanded
C9      A       5       Expanded
C10     B       3       Expanded
```

For the clonality column, I made a loop which identifies rows with counts >= 3 as expanded while rows with counts < 3 as unexpanded.

However, what I wanted to do is to identify rows with counts < 3 as unexpanded, but for rows having counts >= 3, to identify them as Expanded # according to their identity.

I hope my final data frame will look like this:

```
Cell    Ident   Count   Clonality
C1      A       5       Expanded 1
C2      B       3       Expanded 2
C3      A       5       Expanded 1
C4      C       2       Unexpanded
C5      A       5       Expanded 1
C6      B       3       Expanded 2
C7      C       2       Unexpanded
C8      A       5       Expanded 1
C9      A       5       Expanded 1
C10     B       3       Expanded 2
```

I think I need to run a loop but I'm unsure how to modify the loop to do this. The loop I used currently is as below:

```
for (n in 1:nrow(df)){
  count <- df$Count[n]
  if (count >= 3){
    df$Clonality[n] <- "Expanded"
  } else {
    df$Clonality[n] <- "Unexpanded"
  }
}
```

Hope someone could guide me here.

Comment: Please provide the input data in reproducible form. Whether Ident is a factor or not will make a difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this:

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
    mutate_if(is.factor, as.character) %>%
    mutate(Clonality = if_else(
        Clonality == "Expanded",
        sprintf("%s %i", Clonality, as.factor(Ident)),
        Clonality))
#   Cell Ident Count  Clonality
#1    C1     A     5 Expanded 1
#2    C2     B     3 Expanded 2
#3    C3     A     5 Expanded 1
#4    C4     C     2 Unexpanded
#5    C5     A     5 Expanded 1
#6    C6     B     3 Expanded 2
#7    C7     C     2 Unexpanded
#8    C8     A     5 Expanded 1
#9    C9     A     5 Expanded 1
#10  C10     B     3 Expanded 2
```

Explanation: We transform entries in `Clonality` by adding the `factor` level of `Ident` (which means `A` => 1, `B` => 2, and so on), if and only if `Clonality == Expanded`.

---

Or in base R using `transform`

```
df <- transform(df, Clonality = ifelse(
    Clonality == "Expanded",
    sprintf("%s %i", Clonality, as.factor(Ident)),
    as.character(Clonality)))
df
#   Cell Ident Count  Clonality
#1    C1     A     5 Expanded 1
#2    C2     B     3 Expanded 2
#3    C3     A     5 Expanded 1
#4    C4     C     2 Unexpanded
#5    C5     A     5 Expanded 1
#6    C6     B     3 Expanded 2
#7    C7     C     2 Unexpanded
#8    C8     A     5 Expanded 1
#9    C9     A     5 Expanded 1
#10  C10     B     3 Expanded 2
```

---

### Sample data

```
df <- read.table(text =
    "Cell    Ident   Count   Clonality
C1      A       5       Expanded
C2      B       3       Expanded
C3      A       5       Expanded
C4      C       2       Unexpanded
C5      A       5       Expanded
C6      B       3       Expanded
C7      C       2       Unexpanded
C8      A       5       Expanded
C9      A       5       Expanded
C10     B       3       Expanded", header = T)
```